# /give command not working in Minecraft 1.8.8

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

This is the not working command:

```
/give @p golden_sword 1 0 {Unbreakable:1,ench:[{id:9,lvl:0},display:{Name:Gold Sword Of The 1979 Of The GOLDEN AGE,AttributeModifiers:[{Operation:0,UUIDLeast:3,UUIDMost:3,Amount:.1.5,AttributeName:generic.Speed,{AttributeModifiers:[{Operation:0,UUIDLeast:3,UUIDMost:3,Amount:20.0,AttributeName:generic.maxHealth,AttributeModifiers:[{Operation:0,UUIDLeast:3,UUIDMost:3,Amount:1.0,AttributeName:generic.attackDamage}]}
```

It's saying `Unbalanced Curly Brackets {} or Unbalanced Brackets`. I'm using Minecraft version 1.8.8.

Comment: If you have a new question you should ask it separately, not change this to a new question.

Comment: Is this for PE or the Java Edition?

Comment: The unbalanced brackets don't seem to be the only problem, the asker would likely need help with the `AttributeModifier`-tag as well. I'm not sure how to edit the question to include that without breaking it, so I will vote to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

As the error you are getting states, your curly braces are unbalanced - There are not enough closing braces as there are opening ones.

Try this:

```
{
    Unbreakable:1,ench:[{
        id:9,
        lvl:0
    }]
    ,display:{
        Name:Gold Sword Of The 1979 Of The GOLDEN AGE,
        AttributeModifiers:[{
            Operation:0,
            UUIDLeast:3,
            UUIDMost:3,
            Amount:.1.5,
            AttributeName:generic.
            Speed,{
                AttributeModifiers:[{
                    Operation:0,
                    UUIDLeast:3,
                    UUIDMost:3,
                    Amount:20.0,
                    AttributeName:generic.maxHealth,
                    AttributeModifiers:[{
                        Operation:0,
                        UUIDLeast:3,
                        UUIDMost:3,
                        Amount:1.0,
                        AttributeName:generic.attackDamage
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: @LilDavie That *is* the working command. It's just written out neatly with the brackets fixed.

Comment: @LilDavie He basically laid it all out for you right there.  Type `/give @p golden_sword 1 0` and add the JSON text above.

Comment: @LilDavie Are you getting a different error now?

Comment: @LilDavie I think I've spotted the missing one - I've updated the code snippet in my answer.

Comment: Yes, as per previous comment - I've updated the code snippet in my answer.

Comment: While this command fixes the formatting, the command itself is wrong. AttributeModifiers should not exist multiple times in such a nested fashion, it should probably (95% sure) be a list of tags, i.e. `AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:generic.speed,...},{AttributeName:generic.maxHealth,...},...]`. Plus, there are some minor mistakes.

Comment: As well, attribute modifier UUIDs **must** be unique across all modifiers and all items. The UUIDLeast/Most of 3 must be changed such that there are no duplicates.